# Opening hyperlink from div, and load it to the same div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

Currently have

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Check for hash value in URL
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#menu a, #name a, #contact_us a, #item a, #text a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.php #pagearea';
            $('#pagearea').load(toLoad)
        } 
    });


    $('#menu a, #name a, #contact_us a, #item a, #text a').click(function(e){
                if($(e.target).is('foo')){
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "/current/forum";
                return;
                }

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#pagearea').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#pagearea').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#pagearea').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

    });
});
```

Works well. Except when a link from inside #pagearea is followed. It goes to just the php page instead. I found the following topics

Answer: Update JQuery. Was using an outdated version. Problem has been fixed itself.

Comment: show your html code

Comment: please review following link this may help you: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-jquery-load-content-page-without-iframe

Comment: I'm hesitant to include my html because it's quite long and this topic has been slammed a lot for 'including unnecessary' information, but I will do it now requested. I'm trying to follow the link you sent me to but I'm having a bit of a struggle atm.

Comment: After reviewing the link further I've failed to find how I can utilize it in my current situation, afaik from the links I cited in my post .live(click) shouldn't be used anymore either?

Comment: if my understanding is proper then when you click on any  menu item home,about, pictures it will load related data in the div where at present default content is write as "Reserved for content and page area loading"

Comment: That is correct my friend. And then say, for example, if I go to the Pictures page (which will load in div #pagearea), and then want to follow another link from Pictures (say, trees.php), how do I make that replace the div content? At the moment it would just to website.com/trees.php showing the plain page, instead of loading the page in the #pagearea div.

Comment: roger I have update piece of code can you try it on your machine?

Comment: review plunkr as well https://embed.plnkr.co/Wcme60Kgze127Apaufq0/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/5ycSxh9Fqav15PCcRITX?p=preview This is another plunkr in which I have fixed homepage link also and review my answer also roger

Comment: let me know if it's helpful or not if not then where do you stuck

Comment: Will do friend just give me some time to look over it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is working fine with php and html both file

index.html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="default.php" class="menu" data-url="index">Home</a>|
    <a href="about.php" class="menu" data-url="about">About</a>|
    <a href="picture.php" class="menu" data-url="picture">Pictures</a>|
    <a href="videos.php" class="menu" data-url="videos">Videos</a>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
 $("document").ready(function() {    
    loadPage("default.html");
    $(".menu").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fullPath = $(this).attr("href");
        loadPage(fullPath);
    });
    function loadPage(fullPath){
        $("#pagearea").load(fullPath, function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that supposed to replace my entire code? I can't make it work... :\

Comment: no it will just replace your div not whole div

Comment: did you refer plunkr url

Comment: Okay I had a look at the plunkers. To show what I mean (I';m sorry I don't know how to update your plunker) but go to pictures.html, then create this link to videos.html       <a href = "videos.html">Click me for test!</a>   Now from index, navigate to pictures, and click the Videos.html link. you will see it doesn't replace the div content but instead goes to the webpage www.site.com/videos.html    this make sense now my friend?

Comment: ok got it is not about parent page but you want to navigate from child to parent page not parent to parent page

Comment: Man this is not fulfill with load you should do programming with php and do the things.

Comment: basically load will use to get remote content and place in particular div in same page not parent to child page navigation. I created plunkr based on your question but your question should be like that how to  load data with load() function from child page to parent page.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't familiar with these words parent page child page, I realy did try to be as clear as I could. I had a MUCH clearer post up but I got abused for it and made to make it "more concise" lol. My page is currently in PHP but as far as I know PHP can't do what I want. I want an iFrame on my page permanently that doesn't refresh each time I navigate to a new page. I was told AJAX was the only way to do this and not PHP? I will give you my current PHP code maybe you know how to make it change pages without reloading iframe each time

Comment: See my original post for the PHP code I mentioned

Comment: ok so for this whole purpose you create first dynamic template div and based on route you could link pages and for inner page the same thing would happen.

Comment: I'm actually an idiot. I had an outdated jquery version (1.2.3 I think). As soon as I updated, problem fixed itself with origianl code. Thank you so much for your time and words can not express how sorry I am I have wasted your time my friend.

Answer (score 0):

sigh
sighisghisgh

Original code works perfectly fine. Update Jquery. For crying out loud. I'd laugh. But that's a day and a half I can't get back.